# Arduino Serial.read() only reads the second input

Tags: arduino-uno

Whenever I type in the serial monitor, the Arduino only reads the second user input.

I'm try to create a 4 motors (A,B,C,D) where it will move when I type the speed then the letter of the motor. ex.(180a) moves the motor at 180 speed.

I don't understand why the serial only reads at the second time I type the command. It works but that's the only problem.

Here is my code:

```
// Pins for motor A
const int a_pwm_pin = 9;
const int a_dir1_pin = 8;
const int a_dir2_pin = 7;

// Pins for motor B
const int b_pwm_pin = 10;
const int b_dir1_pin = 11;
const int b_dir2_pin = 12;

// Pins for motor C
const int c_pwm_pin = 4;
const int c_dir1_pin = 3;
const int c_dir2_pin = 2;


// Pins for motor D
const int d_pwm_pin = 5;
const int d_dir1_pin = 6;
const int d_dir2_pin = 13;

void setup() {

// Set up pins for motor A
pinMode(a_pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(a_dir1_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(a_dir2_pin, OUTPUT);

// Set up pins for motor B
pinMode(b_pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(b_dir1_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(b_dir2_pin, OUTPUT);
  
// Set up pins for motor C
pinMode(c_pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(c_dir1_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(c_dir2_pin, OUTPUT);
  
// Set up pins for motor D
pinMode(d_pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(d_dir1_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(d_dir2_pin, OUTPUT);
  
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
    
if (Serial.available() > 4)
  {
    int speed;
    delay(2);
    char command = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(command);
    switch (command)
    {
    case 'a': speed = Serial.parseInt();
      // A Motor Movement
      aforward(speed);
      break;

    case 'b': speed = Serial.parseInt();
      // B Motor Movement
      bforward(speed);
      break;
      
    case 'c': speed = Serial.parseInt();
      // C Motor Movement
      cforward(speed);
      break;

    case 'd': speed = Serial.parseInt();
      // D Motor Movement
      dforward(speed);
      break;

    default: Serial.println("");
    }
  }

}

// Drive forward
void aforward(int speed) {

// Check to make sure speed is 0-255
if ( speed < 0 ) {
speed = 0;
}
if ( speed > 255 ) {
speed = 255;
}

// Motor A forward
digitalWrite(a_dir1_pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(a_dir2_pin, LOW);
analogWrite(a_pwm_pin, speed);

}

void bforward(int speed) {

// Check to make sure speed is 0-255
if ( speed < 0 ) {
speed = 0;
}
if ( speed > 255 ) {
speed = 255;
}


// Motor B forward
digitalWrite(b_dir1_pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(b_dir2_pin, LOW);
analogWrite(b_pwm_pin, speed);

}

void cforward(int speed) {

// Check to make sure speed is 0-255
if ( speed < 0 ) {
speed = 0;
}
if ( speed > 255 ) {
speed = 255;
}

// Motor C forward
digitalWrite(c_dir1_pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(c_dir2_pin, LOW);
analogWrite(c_pwm_pin, speed);

}

void dforward(int speed) {

// Check to make sure speed is 0-255
if ( speed < 0 ) {
speed = 0;
}
if ( speed > 255 ) {
speed = 255;
}

// Motor D forward
digitalWrite(d_dir1_pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(d_dir2_pin, LOW);
analogWrite(d_pwm_pin, speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few problems with your code. First, your serial.available if the statement will not be true until the 5th character, "> 4" is "greater than 4" making that to "is greater than or equal, would fix that issue. The other problem is your using Serial.parseInt() in every "case" statement. Move that to the top so it is only run once. I have created a working loop that you can just copy into your project and things should work. Have a good day and leave a comment if somethings not working or any questions you might have.

```
void loop(){
if (Serial.available() >= 4)
  {
    delay(2);
    int speed = Serial.parseInt();
    char command = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(command);
    switch (command)
    {
    case 'a':
      // A Motor Movement
      aforward(speed);
      break;

    case 'b':
      // B Motor Movement
      bforward(speed);
      break;
      
    case 'c':
      // C Motor Movement
      cforward(speed);
      break;

    case 'd':
      // D Motor Movement
      dforward(speed);
      break;

    default: Serial.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I tried your code and it worked, also, thanks for explaining the "serial.available()" part I really didn't understand the concept.